# No database selected mysqli message

Tags: php, mysqli

i changed mysql codes in a project to mysqli but now i got message " No database selected" although all database information is right here is the code :

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');  // Your database Username
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'); // Your database Password
define('DB_DATABASE', 'social'); // Your database Name    
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());
$database = mysqli_select_db($connection,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_query($connection,$database);

mysqli_query($connection,"SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = 'UTF8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = 'UTF8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = 'UTF8'");  
$path = "uploads/";
$LogoPaht="css/icons/";
$conversation_uploads = "conversation_images/";
$profile_image_path = "user_profile_uploads/";
$admin_path = "../".$LogoPaht;
$admin_profile_path='../'.$profile_image_path;
$admin_path_uploads='../'.$path;
$profile_cover_pic_path = "user_profile_cover_uploads/"; // User Profile Cover File
$perpage=10; // Updates perpage
$base_url='http://localhost/sociall/'; // base_url
$admin_base_url=$base_url.'smadmin/'; // Admin base_url
$gravatar=0; // 0 false 1 true gravatar image
$rowsPerPage=1000000; //friends list
$profilePerPage=3;

/*SMTP Details */
$smtpUsername='yourname@gmail.com'; //yourname@gmail.com or you can use your webmail like somename@yourwebsitename.com
$smtpPassword='pass';  //gmail password or your webmail password
$smtpHost='ssl://mail.yourwebsitename.com'; //tls://smtp.gmail.com if yo
$smtpPort='465'; //465
$smtpFrom='yourname@gmail.com'; //yourname@gmail.com}
?>
```

Comment: What is `mysqli_query($connection, $database)` supposed to do? `$database` is a boolean, not a SQL query string.

Comment: FYI, you can specify the database as the fourth argument to `mysqli_connect`, you don't need to call `mysqli_select_db` separately.

Comment: mysqli_* functions don't have the same API as the mysql_* functions. Please check the manual and update the functions

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php Read on mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines:

```
$database = mysqli_select_db($connection,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_query($connection,$database);
```

Add the Database name to your connection establishment request by changing your code to this:

```
 define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');  // Your database Username
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'); // Your database Password
 define('DB_DATABASE', 'social'); // Your database Name    

 // specify the database name when establishing the connection
 $connection = 
    mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

 /***
    If your code dies before this comment, somethings wrong with 
    your credentials, the db name, or the db's not running on the host 
    you're trying to connect to
 ***/


 // should be able to query away if connection succeeded...
 mysqli_query($connection,"SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
   ...
   ...
```

If your connection is failing, it's could bebecause your mysql is setup for port access not socket access.  Change the db line to test:

```
 define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
```

If this fails you're sure you're using a socket, keep it to `localhost` and verify you're user has localhost permissions to the mysql db.

Comment: i changed my code to your code but still the same

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif which specific query `mysqli_query($connection,"...." );` results in the Mysql Error your seeing?

Comment: there is no mysqli error , i just got a message i think all queries done but i don't know why i get this message " No database seelcted "

Comment: After the line `$connection =  mysqli_connect(...);`, get rid of the `die(mysqli_error());` and do a `var_dump($connection); exit;`.   Does the dump it display a connection object?

Comment: yes i got 2 objects , that's the first one :

Comment: object(mysqli)[1]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'client_info' => null
  public 'client_version' => null
  public 'connect_errno' => null
  public 'connect_error' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'host_info' => null
  public 'info' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'server_info' => null
  public 'server_version' => null
  public 'stat' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'protocol_version' => null
  public 'thread_id' => null
  public 'warning_count' => null

Comment: ok, so no error up till that point.  After the line `mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = 'UTF8'");  `, exit out.  Do you see any error?

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif Make sure you delete the lines `$database = mysqli_select_db($connection,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_query($connection,$database);
`

Comment: i think the commands works , but i still got a message no database selected as a text not a mysqli error !

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif your connection is failing.  you need to verify the db name and permissions for the user you're connecting as can legitmately connect from the host you're connecting from.

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif A common error is using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` when your mysql db is setup to listen on a port instead of a socket.